# Prolog: list of lists (size N x N)

Tags: list, matrix, prolog

I need to make list of the lists witch will be some kind of matrix, in size N x N for same N, and I don't know how to declare that all the elements of list must be lists with N elements?

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
n_matrix(N, Rows) :-
        length(Rows, N),
        maplist(length_list(N), Rows).

length_list(L, Ls) :- length(Ls, L).
```

Example:

```
?- n_matrix(2, Rows).
Rows = [[_G294, _G297], [_G300, _G303]].
```

Alternatively, you can use `findall/3`:

```
n_matrix(N, Rows) :-
        findall(Row, (between(1,N,_),length(Row, N)), Rows).
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way to make a list of length N is with `length/2`:

```
?- length(L, 5).
L = [_G1233, _G1236, _G1239, _G1242, _G1245].
```

You could easily apply that a number of times to get the result you want:

```
make_matrix(N, M) :- once(make_matrix(0, N, M)).

make_matrix(N, N, []).
make_matrix(I, N, [Row|Rows]) :-
    length(Row, N),
    I1 is I + 1,
    make_matrix(I1, N, Rows).
```

Used:

```
?- make_matrix(5, M).
M = [[_G479, _G482, _G485, _G488, _G491], 
     [_G497, _G500, _G503, _G506, _G509], 
     [_G515, _G518, _G521, _G524, _G527], 
     [_G533, _G536, _G539, _G542, _G545], 
     [_G551, _G554, _G557, _G560|...]].
```

There are probably more elegant ways to do this.

**Edit**: here's a somewhat more general way to do this without cuts and with `clpfd`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

matrix(1,M,[L]) :- length(L, M).
matrix(N,M,[Row1|L]) :- 
  N #> 1, 
  N0 #= N-1,
  length(L, M),
  matrix(N0,M,L).
```

Comment: The CLP(FD) version seems not quite right yet: `? - matrix(2, 2, Rows)` for example yields a too deeply nested list.